# UIView/UIButton coordinates flipped

Tags: ipad, uiview, ios6, core-plot

I have a coreplot project. The class of the view in viewcontroller has been changed to CPTGraphHostingView.

After creating the graph (this works fine), 
I am adding a button as a subview , this launches a popover
the button shown is inverted. I have the same control in different view controllers and it works fine. The Popover also appears fine.

Here is the code that creates and adds the UIButton

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(monthSelection)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Change Month" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(330, 650, 111, 40);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

[here is a screenshot of whats happening. UIButton is suppose to show somewhere below the popover. What am i missing.

[image: here is a screenshot of whats happening. UIButton is suppose to show somewhere below the popover. What am i missing.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add subviews to the graph hosting view. Instead, make other views siblings of the hosting view, i.e., add them as subviews of the same superview.